# How can I move the logo in Twenty Seventeen Theme Next to the menu bar

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

I am rebuilding my website using the Twenty Seventeen Theme, an I would like to have the logo appear in the menu bar rather than in the center of the featured image. I found a site that has exactly what I am looking to do. You can see it [here](https://www.jltreeservice.com) can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through css. The site you are referring to uses `display:table` for both logo and navigation. I would probably use `display:inline-block` and/or floats instead to achieve this.

I would highly recommend you use a child theme for this so the Twenty Seventeen code base stays intact. You can find out about how to use child theme [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) at the wordpress codex.

I would also like to recommend using [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) or a similar developer tool to peek at the code of other websites.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I am using a child theme, and I have tried several CSS Code recommendations that I found elsewhere but have had no luck.